# clang-format: macro in a function

Tags: clang-format

Some c code
Before format:

```c
#define MS_DEF(type) extern type

MS_DEF(int) my_func(int a, int b, int c, const char *x, const char *y, const char *z)
{
  // do something
  return 0;
}
```

After format (clang-format --style=LLVM test.c) :

```c
#define MS_DEF(type) extern type

MS_DEF(int)
my_func(int a, int b, int c, const char *x, const char *y, const char *z) {
  // do something
  return 0;
}
```

I want to keep MS_DEF(int) and my_func in same line

```
MS_DEF(int) my_func(...)
```

How to do? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `TypenameMacros` style option is intended exactly for such cases.

Try adding the following to your `.clang-format` configuration file:

```yaml
TypenameMacros: ['MS_DEF']
```

With just that option, the formatted result is as following

```cpp
#define MS_DEF(type) extern type

MS_DEF(int) my_func(int a, int b, int c, const char *x, const char *y,
                    const char *z) {
  // do something
  return 0;
}
```